# Is this a valid expansion of $\log(\sin(x))$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

I was playing around with Euler’s infinite product for the sine function, when it occurred to me.

$$\sin(x)=x\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$

$$\log(\sin(x))=\log(x)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$

Is this a valid series expansion? I assume so. Also, over what interval does it converge?

Comment: What do you understand by expansion? If you want a Taylor expansion, then you must get a power expansion. The expansion in Fourier or some other orthogonal system will be different.

Comment: You used two theorems from Algebra/Calculus here: (a) $\log$ of a finite product equals to the sum of $\log$'s of the factors; (b) $\log$ of the limit is the same as limit of the $\log$'s (because $\log$ is continuous). It is to be noted that both theorems have caveats: (a) the terms must be positive, (b) the limit must exist and be positive. From those you can go backwards and calculate the range of $x$. Without spending too much time on this: $x\in(0,\pi)$ seems to me as a necessary _and_ sufficient condition for the second equality both to make sense and to be valid.

Comment: Yes, however it is important to note that this is a complex set-valued function, since if for example $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$, then $\sin(x)=-1$, so the main branch of $\log\sin(x)=i\pi$. You can see this from the inner $\log$ as well, since $1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}$ can easily be negative too.

Comment: @DanielP, yes, _provided that the OP was even doing complex analysis_. Having no complex analysis tags on this question, my guess is that they are not. My guess is that this is a _real analysis_ question. @ Person Could you please confirm?

Comment: It appears the sum converges for all $x$. However, it does not converge to the same branch of $\ln \sin x$ for all $x$. That is, $\ln \sin x$ and that sum may differ by some multiple of $2i\pi$.